# Django django-rest-auth shows "New password has been saved" when giving wrong oldpassword

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using Django and django-rest-auth for authentication.

When posting:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Token sometoken" -d 

"oldpassword=somepassword&new_password1=somenewpassword&new_password2=somenewpassword" 

 http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/password/change/
```

I always get

"detail":"New password has been saved."

Even if I don´t give the right password in the oldpassword field.

Any idea why this happens and if there is a way to make sure the oldpassword entered is the current password? Is oldpassword maybe an optional field I can make required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to set `OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True` in your settings.py.

See https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html